# Sum the value in Dataverse and safe it in a different table

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

i am using the Power Plattform to create a table and also use the dataverse as my database. I have created two tables.

Table `Planned Study Cost` one looks like the following:

| Column | Column Type |
| --- | --- |
| Type Of Cost | Optionset |
| Cost | Currency |
| Refunded Study Cost | Currency |

This table is just for planning what costs will come up in the future.

Lets say i have an entry like the following:

Type Of Cost: "semester fee"
Cost: "1000,00€"
Refunded Study Cost: "0,00"

I also have a second table `Proven Study Cost`. This table is there to prove the costs which are created in the `Planned Study Cost` table.

| Column | Column Type |
| --- | --- |
| Type Of Cost | Optionset |
| Refunded Cost | Currency |

So when ever an entry in this table is created, the value of the `Refunded Cost` column should be updated in the `Planned Study Cost` table for the matching `Type Of Cost`

Lets say we have an entry like this in the `Proven Study Cost`:

Type Of Cost: "semester fee"
Refunded Study Cost: "500,00"

Then the entry in the beginning of the `Planned Study Cost` table should be updated and look like this:

Type Of Cost: "semester fee"
Cost: "1000,00€"
Refunded Study Cost: "500,00"

and so on.

Is there a possibility to either create this directly in the Power App itself or maybe create a cloud flow (which might be the better attempt?)

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is there a relationship between the two tables Or these tables are linked by the type of cost? if later then the type of cost should be a optionset or lookup field as keeping text as a link has serious trouble with user typing wrongly or case mismatch.

Comment: @Harinarayanan, yes there is a relationship between the tables and sorry you are right, i got that wrong. It is an optionset where the user can select the "Type Of Cost". The relation is a 1:n relation between "Planned Study Cost" and "Proven Study Cost" (in that order). I have a lookup from "Proven Study Cost" to "Planned Study Cost"

Comment: So, what is expected if there are multiple proven study cost for a planned study cost? you are expecting to sum of values or the latest updated value goes in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarifications, based on the comments you would like to sum up the values from child entity to a field in parent entity.

You have many options to achieve this, I will explain two ways which are low/no code way.

1. Use Rollup fields, which basically is a dataverse capability to rollup the calcuations and update parent entity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/calculated-rollup-attributes

> Please check the limitations of this column type before you choose
> this option. As the calculation might not happen real-time.

2. Use automated cloud flow to do the necessary calculations on create/update/delete of the child entity to recalculate the values. here you control how and when it calculation happens and more flexibility.

Other ways include plugins, custom workflows which might need some custom code to work.